# How to GroupBy Virtual Column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Hello I have problems Table for Reeves and I am trying to check which reeve creates most problem. So here is my Problem Model;

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public short Sira { get; set; }
public DateTime Created { get; set; }
public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }
public virtual Member WhoIs { get; set; }
public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
public virtual Town Town { get; set; }
public virtual District District { get; set; }
public virtual Reeve Reeve { get; set; }
```

As you see I have Reeve as a virtual table.When I create table I get `Reeve_Id` and Trying to `.GroupBy(m => m.Reeve.Id)` So here is the code ;

```
public ActionResult GroupByReeve()
    {
        var model = new ProblemModel
        {

            ProblemsList = Db.Problems.GroupBy(m => m.Reeve.Id)
            .Select(s => new ProblemModel.ProblemForView
            {

                Id = s.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                CountItem = s.Count(),
                AllItem = Db.Problems.Count(),
               ReeveName=s.FirstOrDefault().Reeve.Name

            })

        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

So I can groupby problems by their Id not by ReeveId.The view returns 4 items(4 problems) But they are belong to only 2 Reeves So it must show 2 items not 4 items. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, why your code doesn't work (it looks like it should), but here is how you use GroupBy properly:

```
ProblemsList = Db.Problems.GroupBy(m => m.Reeve.Id,
                                   s => new ProblemModel.ProblemForView
        {

            Id = s.FirstOrDefault().Id,
            CountItem = s.Count(),
            AllItem = Db.Problems.Count(),
            ReeveName=s.FirstOrDefault().Reeve.Name

        });
```